# AssertionError: No inf checks were recorded for this optimizer

Tags: python, pytorch, alpaca

Code was based off on https://github.com/tloen/alpaca-lora/blob/main/finetune.py

My objective of this training was to made use of unsupervised training dataset to get the model to understand how words are written in my domain (basically masked language modelling). Reason i don't use the conventional instructional fine tuning is because there's no such dataset of sufficient quantity available to me.

The 2 main changes i've made are as follows

1. instead of fine tuning from Llama's weights, i'll finetune from a existing alpaca-lora's weight. As such, i've edited the code as follows

```
from peft import (
    # LoraConfig,
    PeftModel,
    get_peft_model,
    get_peft_model_state_dict,
    prepare_model_for_int8_training,
    set_peft_model_state_dict,
)
```

as well as

```
# config = LoraConfig(
    #     r=lora_r,
    #     lora_alpha=lora_alpha,
    #     target_modules=lora_target_modules,
    #     lora_dropout=lora_dropout,
    #     bias="none",
    #     task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
    # )
    # model = get_peft_model(model, config)

    # replace with this to load directly from alpaca
    LORA_WEIGHTS = "tloen/alpaca-lora-7b"
    model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(
        model,
        LORA_WEIGHTS,
        torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    )
```

2. edited the dataset to my own. (I am not using the prompt template). My code for generating the dataset as follows:

```
def chunk_text(data):
    concantenated_text = ''
    all_result = []
    for i in range(data['train'].num_rows):
        concantenated_text += data['train']['combined'][i]
    tokenized_concantenated_text = tokenizer.encode(concantenated_text)[1:]
    tokenized_prompt = tokenizer.encode("### Text: ")[1:]
    full_length = len(tokenized_concantenated_text)
    for i in range(0, full_length, chunk_size):
        text = tokenized_concantenated_text[i: i+chunk_size+overlap_size] 
        text = tokenized_prompt + text
        text = tokenizer.decode(text)
        
        result = tokenizer(text, padding=False)
        if result["input_ids"][-1] != tokenizer.eos_token_id:
            result["input_ids"].append(tokenizer.eos_token_id)
            result["attention_mask"].append(1)

        result["labels"] = result["input_ids"].copy()

        all_result.append(result)
    return all_result
```

However, i keep facing the following error no matter how i tweak the code. Really appreciate any help rendered!

```
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ in <cell line: 2>:2                                                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1662 in train                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1659 │   │   inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(                                 │
│   1660 │   │   │   self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size  │
│   1661 │   │   )                                                                                 │
│ ❱ 1662 │   │   return inner_training_loop(                                                       │
│   1663 │   │   │   args=args,                                                                    │
│   1664 │   │   │   resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,                                │
│   1665 │   │   │   trial=trial,                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1991 in _inner_training_loop      │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1988 │   │   │   │   │   │   │   xm.optimizer_step(self.optimizer)                             │
│   1989 │   │   │   │   │   elif self.do_grad_scaling:                                            │
│   1990 │   │   │   │   │   │   scale_before = self.scaler.get_scale()                            │
│ ❱ 1991 │   │   │   │   │   │   self.scaler.step(self.optimizer)                                  │
│   1992 │   │   │   │   │   │   self.scaler.update()                                              │
│   1993 │   │   │   │   │   │   scale_after = self.scaler.get_scale()                             │
│   1994 │   │   │   │   │   │   optimizer_was_run = scale_before <= scale_after                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/cuda/amp/grad_scaler.py:368 in step                 │
│                                                                                                  │
│   365 │   │   if optimizer_state["stage"] is OptState.READY:                                     │
│   366 │   │   │   self.unscale_(optimizer)                                                       │
│   367 │   │                                                                                      │
│ ❱ 368 │   │   assert len(optimizer_state["found_inf_per_device"]) > 0, "No inf checks were rec   │
│   369 │   │                                                                                      │
│   370 │   │   retval = self._maybe_opt_step(optimizer, optimizer_state, *args, **kwargs)         │
│   371                                                                                            │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
AssertionError: No inf checks were recorded for this optimizer.
```

Environment:
Python: 3.9
cuda: 11.8

Comment: May I ask if you resolved the issue? I am experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

For anybody struggling with this issue because they are loading a pretrained config, there may be a flag for `inference_mode` which needs to be changed:

```py
LORA_WEIGHTS = 'tloen/alpaca-lora-7b'
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, LORA_WEIGHTS, dtype=torch.float16)

config = LoraConfig.from_pretrained(LORA_WEIGHTS)
config.inference_mode = False

model = get_peft_model(model, config)
```

With `inference_mode` set to `True` you are freezing the adapter ([source code](https://github.com/huggingface/peft/blob/main/src/peft/tuners/lora.py)):

```py
if self.peft_config[adapter_name].inference_mode:
  _freeze_adapter(self.model, adapter_name)
```

Comment: when using `PeftModel.from_pretrained` (as in the question) you can set this by passing `is_trainable=True`

Answer (score 1):

I removed --mixed_precision="fp16" from training script and it removed my error.

Comment: This worked for me. I set `fp16=False` in `transformers.TrainingArguments()`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't comment the config, and initialize the `model = get_peft_model(model, config)` after `model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, LORA_WEIGHTS, torch_dtype=torch.float16)`

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question but rather provides an alternative recommended way of achieving the same objective. Alternately, you can try to export the Llama+Loraweights as huggingface checkpoint locally using `export_hf_checkpoint.py` file. This saved checkpoint becomes the new base model and you can tune a new LoRA model on top of this new base model.